# invoke coq typechecker from external programs

Tags: coq

What would be the best way to interact with Coq from an external program? For example, let's say I want to programmatically generate programs / proofs in some language other than Coq and I just want to call Coq to typecheck them. Is there a standard way to do something like that?

Comment: E.g. [Logitext](http://logitext.mit.edu/main) interacts with Coq to check the validity of sequential calculus proofs.

Comment: Which implementation language are you using? Seems to me you want a system call to `coqc`.

Comment: Search a bit in the site for some existing answers. In general, typechecking is best done using the ML API.

Comment: This is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46032067/2747511).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. Construct `.v` files, invoke `coqc`, check the return code and parse the output of `coqc`.

This is, in some sense, the most stable way to interact with Coq.  It has the most inter-version stability.  It's also the most inflexible; you create a `.v` file, and check it all in one go.

For an example of this method, see [my Coq bug minimizer](https://github.com/JasonGross/coq-tools/blob/master/find-bug.py) (specificially [`get_coq_output` in `diagnose_error.py`](https://github.com/JasonGross/coq-tools/blob/5e5cbb8c1f173606ee8e6f268d6390f1c3b6ece5/diagnose_error.py#L135)), which repeatedly makes small alterations to a `.v` file and checks to see that the alterations don't change the error message given by `coqc`.

2. Use the XML protocol to communicate with coqtop

This is the method used by CoqIDE and by [upcoming versions of ProofGeneral](https://github.com/psteckler/ProofGeneral/tree/server-protocol).  [Logitext](http://logitext.mit.edu/main) [invokes from Haskell](https://github.com/ezyang/logitext/blob/master/CoqTop.hs) a custom patched version of `coqtop` with the pgip protocol, which was an earlier attempt at a more standardized way of communication with the prover (see [this issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/2705) for more details).

This is becoming more stable, and gives more fine-grained control over what you want checked.  For example, it allows you to check multiple proofs within a single session, which is important if you depend on a large library that takes time to load, and need to check many small proofs.

3. Write a custom OCaml toplevel wrapper for the interface to Coq that you want

The main example of this that I'm aware of is [PIDEtop](https://bitbucket.org/coqpide/pidetop), which is used in the [Coqoon Eclipse plugin](http://coqoon.github.io/).  I suspect that some of the other entries in the GUI section of [Related Tools](https://coq.inria.fr/related-tools) use this method.

Note that `coqtop` is itself a toplevel wrapper in this style; the files in the [`toplevel/` folder of the Coq project](https://github.com/coq/coq/tree/master/toplevel) are likely to be informative.

This gives you the most flexibility and reusability, at the cost of having to design your own protocol, or implement an existing protocol.

4. Write your external program in OCaml and link with Coq

Much like (3), this method gives you as much flexibility as you want.  In fact, the only difference between this and (3) is that in (3), you separate out the communication with Coq into its own binary, whereas here, you fuse communication with Coq with the other functionality of your program.  I'm not aware of programs in this style, though I believe `coqchk` may qualify, as I think it shares a couple of files with the Coq kernel (see [the `checker/` folder in the Coq codebase](https://github.com/coq/coq/tree/master/checker)).

---

Regardless of which way you choose, I think that modelling off of existing projects will be more fruitful than making use of (as-yet incomplete) documentation on the various APIs and protocols.  The API has been undergoing a lot of revision recently, in an attempt to get it into a reasonable and stable state, and the XML protocol has also been subject to recent improvements; @ejgallego has been the driving force behind much of these improvements.

Comment: My recommended reference to write a toplevel is sertop https://github.com/ejgallego/coq-serapi/tree/v8.7/sertop which uses a modern build system [jbuilder is on the way] and a ocamlfind-ed Coq. Also, the Coq init API used there is being incorporated to Coq upstream.